# How to differentiate between "Direct" and "Indirect" dependencies in jQAssistant

Tags: java, dependencies, jqassistant

To illustrate my issue, I created [a minimal, fictional example project](https://github.com/moee/jqassistant-implicit-dependency) which consists of three classes, `Service`, `Transaction` and `Product`. P

```java
package org.example;

public class Service {
    public Service(Transaction transaction) {
        int buyerId = transaction.getProduct().getId();
    }
}
```

Type `Product` is in a separate package `domain`

```java
package org.example.domain;

public class Product {
    // [...]
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

For the sake of this example, assume that I want to avoid `Service` to depend on anything in package `domain`.

I can ensure this using this query:

```
MATCH
    (c {name:"Service"})-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(d)
WHERE
    d.fqn STARTS WITH "org.example.domain"
RETURN
    c.fqn, d.fqn
```

This returns a non-empty result, i.e. the constraint is violated - because jQAssistant creates a `:DEPENDS_ON` relationship between `Service` and `Product` in this case, which feels counter-intuitive, because there is neither an import nor a direct reference to `org.example.domain.Product` in `Service`.

This leads me to the following questions:

- Is this behavior intentional or not?
- Is there a way to differentiate between "direct" dependencies where the dependency is imported and used inside the parent type and "indirect" dependencies as illustrated in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is by intention on both the technical and conceptual level:

Technical: While scanning a Java class all encountered dependencies are aggregated. In the example the getProduct() returns a Product and that one is used for invoking a method on it, so it's tracked.

Conceptual: The code *literally* depends on Product. If you remove the type from the classpath, the shown code breaks. Even if there's no import or explicit field/variable/parameter/return type declaration the dependency is still there. If you would like to refactor (e.g. split up domain and services into different artifacts) you would need to address this dependency as well. So you could see it the other way around: Even if you don't see the dependency explicitly in the code it becomes visible by jQA.

Comment: Thanks to @OGierke for the suggestion to further "sharpening" my answer.